# How I can get result of event in browserView?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How I can get result of event in browserView?
I have:

```js
browserView.webContents.executeJavaScript('
  let btn = document.createElement("button")
  btn.innerHTML = "Click Me"
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    return "Button is clicked"
  })
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
').then(r=> console.log(r))
```

What I need to do to get "Button is clicked" after click on button in main process and add to variable?

Comment: is `injectedScript` supposed to be `executeJavaScript`? Do you only need the first click or all subsequent ones? There's an idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229777/how-to-toggle-devtools-in-an-electron-app-while-focused-on-devtools/67547904#67547904)

Comment: @pushkin Yes, `executeJavaScript` and I need every click on button.  Unfortunately your idea does not work for me.

Comment: I guess you could always add a one time handler and then we that promise resolves (based on idea from linked post), you can just inject more code each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solutions we need `preload` for `browserView`:

```js
const browserView = new BrowserView({
            webPreferences: {
                preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') 
            }
        })
```

`preload.js`

```js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let btn = document.createElement("button")
  btn.innerHTML = "Click Me"
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    ipcRenderer.send('message','button is clicked')
  })
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
})
```

And... it works! In main proccess with `ipcMain.on` we received "button is clicked"

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have to find a way to call `ipcRenderer` in the view, ex. `ipcRenderer.send('message', 'hi')`. And in the main thread, you can do `ipcMain.on('message', () => {})`.

But for your question, how do you access `ipcRenderer`? Try

```
  browserView.webContents.executeJavaScript('
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    ipcRenderer.send('message', 'hi')
```

And in the `index.js`

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('message', (e, t) => {
  console.log(t)
})
```

Comment: hm, I guess as a caveat, this only works if the renderer has node enabled in it. The fact that he's resorting to injecting JS into the page suggests to me that this process isn't hosting local content in which case, it would be advisable to sandbox the process and disable node

Comment: This browserView doesn't have node or electron. If this were the case, my question was resolved without stackoverflow. In my case this browserView is third party SPA.

Comment: you basically need to import `ipcRenderer`, with the `require` or not, that's part of your renderer's build process, isn't it? You renderer has to have some sort of `import` or whatever statement to allow pull other source code, otherwise you just have to open the `electron` package and copy paste all the code. That's another option.

Comment: when you use `executeJavaScript`, you add an element, but you can also add a script, that is similar to above `import` or `require` approach, basically you need another piece of source code :)

Comment: this browserView ins't my part of renderer, so I can't use `ipcRenderer` or `require` or `import`. How I can add `ipcRenderer` or `require` to `executeJavaScript` if it doesn't have Electron?

Comment: That's why  you need to import it? Ex. when you write an HTML, there's a line called `<script>`. This line can be added with `executeJavascript` as well, because a script is an element. Basically I'm saying as long as you can do `executeJavascript`, you can make an artificial import, or you can just copy all the source code over.